# Server for Android card game

Tags: android, vb.net, azure, client-server

I have made an Android card game where the user plays versus an AI. Now I want to make it online so a player could play versus another player. Is possible to host the game server (written in vb.net) in Windows Azure?

The server is using TCP connections and it will send a simple message to the client (e.g., "K Spades"), but I also want to have a DB with player names, scores, etc.

The game currently has ~20k players. What hardware/bandwidth will the servers need?
If is not possible to deploy the server on Azure, what should I use?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is "it depends". 20K players generating how much traffic? How much storage does it take now based on just 2 players playing 1 game? How much processing power does it take for a single game? (mutliply that with the potential number of players and games). Check out the [pricing calculator](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full).

Also, check out [auto scaling](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/autoscaling/) where you resources will dynamically scale up and down depending on the traffic it gets at runtime (meaning you don't have to reserve instances ahead of time).

Comment: So, is possible to host my server on azure, right?

Answer (score 0):

20k users should mean that you don't have more then ~ 2k users a day online.
Your game users should use far less traffic, then, for example, web site users.

For a web site, 2k users a day is a funny number, so I guess that you can run server even on your phone : )